# How do I use a "Document Control Number" to access a filing on EDGAR?

Tags: united-states, sec, edgar

I would like to read Reliance Industries Ltd's [Form 12G32BR filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/894648/999999999704012036/9999999997-04-012036-index.htm) on EDGAR. However, the only document in that filing says:

> This document was generated as part of a paper submission.
>
> Please reference the Document Control Number 04010785 for access to the original document.

Does this mean that the filing is not available electronically? If so, how do I use the "Document Control Number" to obtain the document?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [How to Access or Request Records Not Accessible via SEC Website](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/public-documents) for instructions. One method is to use the [Request Records form](https://www.sec.gov/forms/request_public_docs), and enter the "Document Control Number" in the appropriate form field. This will cost at least $61.

Comment: Have you tried the form in my answer? There is apparently no cost for that one.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Not yet. I will try your suggestion first. Give me a few weeks ...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this is right or not, but I found this webpage on SEC.gov:

[Request for Electronic Certification of EDGAR Filings](https://www.sec.gov/forms/request_cert_filings)

Apparently, you fill out the form, and they send you a PDF of the document you need.

You need an “Accession Number” to specify the document you want. For the document you are interested in, the Accession Number is apparently “9999999997-04-012036”, which is shown in the upper right corner of [the filing detail page](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/894648/999999999704012036/9999999997-04-012036-index.htm) you linked to.

---

Update:
On May 5, I decided to test this out and use the form I linked to request the document in the question.  I immediately received an e-mail stating that I would have the document in 4 business days, but it's been one week and I haven't received any more communication.

---

Update 2 (October):
I never did get the document or any further e-mail messages.

Comment: Is there a reason why some EDGAR filings cannot be downloaded directly?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have also submitted the form a few days ago. I have yet to receive the certified filing. I will inform you when I receive further communications from the SEC.